# I tried to read and convert that type of date into a Date format so I can use calendar

Tags: java, date, parsing, calendar, simpledateformat

I need to get from 16Mar2009(mon), 17Mar2009(tues), 18Mar2009(wed) this type of dates the EE (day of the week in numeric) as calendar does, but it keeps crashing.

```
public static Date [] ConvertingFormat(String [] data)
{
    Date [] inDate = new Date [data.length];
    SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy(EE)");
    try
    {
        int i = data.length;
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            inDate [j] = fromUser.parse(data[j]);
        }
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("Error");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return inDate;
}
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part will go outside the bounds of the inDate array

```
int i = data.length;
for (int j=0;j<=i;j++)
{
    inDate [j] = fromUser.parse(data[j]);
}
```

If i == j this will still loop, but inDate will be too small. It has to be j < i

Comment: just realized that and does work fo the first try, but crash on second pass on the for

Comment: yei ty :P 2 less problems still not running :P

Comment: k i realized on the start sentence is 17Mar2009(tues) insted fo (tue), how should i control user from doing that

Comment: That question is abit to broad to answer here ;) It all depends on how the system is set up, but giving the user an example and just telling them when it is wrong (if you cant parse it in the SimpleDateFormat it is wrong) would probably do the trick.

Comment: ty :P problem solved, now fight with the rest of the code :P